# 403 forbidden when redirect to external link by php

Tags: php, vlc, http-status-code-403

I have code that get the playlist link through the page source
Then redirects to this  playlist link 
Through this php file run the playlist on the vlc program by user ageint
He worked without problems but now shows me 403 forbidden
image 
https://i.postimg.cc/7Yw1Fs2f/image.png

Even though I copy the link to the playlist and put it directly inside
vlc with user ageint , Works without any problems..
image 
https://i.postimg.cc/RVd1477G/image.png

Please help me in checking the code

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents("http://wssfree.com/WSSphp/wssbeinsports1/wssbeinsports1.php");

preg_match_all(
     '/(http.*?wmsAuthSign\=[^\&\">]+)/',

    $html,
    $posts, // will contain the article data
    PREG_SET_ORDER // formats data into an array of posts
);

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $link = $post[0];

header('Location:' .$link);
exit;

}
?>
```

and user agent = freeapppsss

Comment: The web server is blocking your request... for some reason.

Comment: Seems like everyone is getting that 403 error, when trying to get to the links even via the browser, please check this.

Comment: im try from local server in windows and from hosting server and when I copy the link to the playlist and put it directly inside vlc with user ageint , Works without any problems. @DanielWilliams

Comment: It's hard to say, but they may have web server rules that only allows certain requests.

Comment: Thank you and wait for the help of others that there is no explanation or solution @DanielWilliams

Comment: You might want to try a CURL request (http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) because the web server may be looking for other headers that PHP is not sending.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the HTML code:

```
<?php

$url = "http://wssfree.com/WSSphp/wssbeinsports1/wssbeinsports1.php";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$html = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo '<textarea>'.$html.'</textarea>';
```

You can then use the variable `$html` to pull out the URL you want.

I do note that that you have a `for` loop that has an `exit();` command for each item, which will kill the PHP page, so you don't need `preg_match_all`, just `preg_match`.

Comment: hello daniel thanks for help.
i edit code according to your suggestions but same problem when reditct to playlist link appears 403 forbidden
$url = "http://wssfree.com/WSSphp/wssbeinsports1/wssbeinsports1.php";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$html = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);


preg_match_all(
    '/(http.*?wmsAuthSign\=[^\&\">]+)/',
   $html,
    $posts
);

$final = ($posts[0][0]);
header("Location:".$final);
try to play on vlc with user agnt

Comment: Even if you try and visit the link in your browser, you get a `forbidden` message. `http://194.88.104.169:8081/wss20/beinsports1ar-2g/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9MTAvOS8yMDE4IDEwOjI4OjA3IFBNJmhhc2hfdmFsdWU9eFJVc0ppZnhtRjN5bXdwWUxmRW5hUT09JnZhbGlkbWludXRlcz0yMA==`

Comment: thanks agin Daniel Williams
I do not use - user agent when i open it from browser just i use it on vlc 
Look at these pictures
https://i.postimg.cc/x1CrRB2j/image.png
Redirects to the playlist link with no problems but appears 403
https://i.postimg.cc/90WgfqXX/screenshot_5.png
When I run the direct link works without problems
https://i.postimg.cc/8kttHcPW/screenshot_6.png
it working >
https://i.postimg.cc/g26smKyq/screenshot_7.png
I think the problem is redirection @Daniel Williams